# Highlighting element under focus using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

What JavaScript code should I use to highlight My web element under focus with some color.
   JavascriptExecutor js=((JavascriptExecutor)driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing background-color of the element

```
element.style.backgroundColor = '#A80000
```

**Example in java**

```
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

JavascriptExecutor js=((JavascriptExecutor)driver);

js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = '#A80000'",search);
```

The above example script will change the color of the search field

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you need any further help